# Php date function does not work

Tags: php, date, time

I am using php date function to get date and time. But **time** information that I got is incorrect.
What can I do for this problem solution?  Thanks..

php code :

```
$d = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

Comment: By incorrect what do you mean? it does not print? if the time is simply wrong, it might be your timezone setting!

Comment: The function works just fine. You either have `h` instead of `H` or you need to set the timezone with `date_default_timezone_set`.

Comment: And if nothing else works you could check if the server's system clock is actually sync'ed with yours.

Comment: No, you have not just discovered a bug in one of the most widely used functions in PHP. Clarify what exactly isn't the way you expect.

Comment: I am new on php so I had forggotten to use timezone. My problem solved. Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

```
$d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the examples shown here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
Careful that 'h' should be capital.

This should fix it but if still doesn't work, is your computers time correct?